# migrate for compute engine cannot attach network card to vm migrated from VMware

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-migrate-for-compute-engine

I have migrated a VM with a size of 7TB of information distributed on 18 disks, in the migration no errors are recorded, however when the test-clone job is executed it cannot attach the network card, a screenshot of the machine and it is observed that the operating system starts without problem, but since it does not have a network card it is not accessible.

The migrate for compute engine used was version 5
The S.O to migrate is Windows server 2012 R2

```
Serial port 1 output for svr-gcp-sysdb-02
[2J[01;01H[=3h[2J[01;01HCSM BBS Table full.

UEFI: Failed to load image.
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk 
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x1,0x0)
OptionNumber: 1.
Status: Not Found.

BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0001 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x1,0x0): Not Found

UEFI: Failed to load image.
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk  2
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x2,0x0)
OptionNumber: 2.
Status: Not Found.

BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0002 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk  2" from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x2,0x0): Not Found
BdsDxe: loading Boot0003 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk  3" from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x3,0x0)
BdsDxe: starting Boot0003 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk  3" from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x3,0x0)

UEFI: Attempting to start image.
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk  3
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x3,0x0)
OptionNumber: 3.

[1m[37m[40m[01;01H[2J[01;01H[2J[01;01H[=3h[2J[01;01HCSM BBS Table full.

UEFI: Failed to load image.
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk 
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x1,0x0)
OptionNumber: 1.
Status: Not Found.

BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0001 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x1,0x0): Not Found

UEFI: Failed to load image.
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk  2
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x2,0x0)
OptionNumber: 2.
Status: Not Found.

BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0002 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk  2" from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x2,0x0): Not Found
BdsDxe: loading Boot0003 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk  3" from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x3,0x0)
BdsDxe: starting Boot0003 "UEFI Google PersistentDisk  3" from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x3,0x0)

UEFI: Attempting to start image.
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk  3
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x3,0x0)
OptionNumber: 3.

[1m[37m[40m[01;01H[2J[01;01H[2J[01;01H[=3h[2J[01;01HCSM BBS Table full.
BdsDxe: loading Boot0025 "Windows Boot Manager" from HD(2,GPT,F8D89693-113C-47C3-8450-A857FE031087,0x96800,0x31800)/\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
BdsDxe: starting Boot0025 "Windows Boot Manager" from HD(2,GPT,F8D89693-113C-47C3-8450-A857FE031087,0x96800,0x31800)/\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi

UEFI: Attempting to start image.
Description: Windows Boot Manager
FilePath: HD(2,GPT,F8D89693-113C-47C3-8450-A857FE031087,0x96800,0x31800)/\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
OptionNumber: 37.

[1m[37m[40m[01;01H[2J[01;01H
Starting firstboot script
PSVersion: 3.0
PID: 2204

Running the following scripts (in order):
 * 00_configure_network.ps1
 * 01_install_googet_packages.ps1
 * 02_activate_instance.ps1
 * 03_uninstall_vmware_tools.ps1

Running 00_configure_network.ps1...

Timed out waiting for netkvm device after 600 seconds 
Attempting to repair network settings...
584 
Clean remove returned NO_ERROR

Exception deleting key + System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

at Win32.ResetDevice.DeleteKey(String devicePath) in c:\Windows\Temp\n23ykcju.0.cs:line 282 (GetLastError: 122)
DeleteKey returned FAILED_TO_DELETE_SUBEKEY

Failed waiting for installation end. WaitResult=4294967295 (GetLastError: 2)
Reinstall returned FAILED_WAITING_FOR_PNP

FAILED_WAITING_FOR_PNP
Network Adapter not found - skipping network configuration 
At C:\Google\Migrate\Firstboot\scripts\00_configure_network.ps1:45 char:9
   throw 'Network Adapter not found - skipping network configuration'
   
   CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Network Adapter...k configuration:String) [], RuntimeException FullyQualifiedErrorId : Network Adapter not found - skipping network con figuration
```

Can someone know what the error is?

Comment: Can you confirm that there actually is a virtual NIC attached? My best bet would be toggling from the driver `VMXNET3` to `E1000` - or vice versa. `netkvm` hints for this driver: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/kvmnet/installer

Comment: Your problem is not with network adapters. Your problem is the boot disk cannot be mounted. The firmware then scans other disks looking for a boot image. I do not know the solution but networking is not **yet** your problem. I recommend that you open a Google Cloud Support case as I am now aware of public methods of modifying the UEFI boot process.

Comment: I have opened the case 8 days ago and they are looking for a solution.

Comment: Provide more information, like the process you followed to migrate the VM, OS and version, etc. Think of it as the minimal information needed to attempt a reproduction of the issue.

Comment: the migrate for compute engine used was version 5, the S.O to migrate is Windows server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

The logs suggest an issue loading the image because the boot disk’s options cannot be found:

```
UEFI: Failed to load image.
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk 
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x1,0x0)
OptionNumber: 1.
Status: Not Found.

UEFI: Failed to load image. 
Description: UEFI Google PersistentDisk 2 
FilePath: PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x3,0x0)/Scsi(0x2,0x0) 
OptionNumber: 2. 
Status: Not Found.
```

Without the logs on the GCP side, it is very hard to troubleshoot this. The best approach is to [collect diagnostic information](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/collecting-diagnostic-information) from the VM and then open up a case with Google through the [Support Center](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DeviceInstall\Parameters\DeviceInstallDisabled

being set.

After that PNP timed-out and required increasing:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Settings\InstallTimeout